# Menu resource not found

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, resources

I started a new project and it's a problem I haven't encountered yet.

It's a simple job that other times worked, create a menu for the toolbar Android Resource Directory -> Resource Type 'menu'. It seems it doesn't recognize the menu from the resources.

[image]

and using import android.R doesn't work because it doesn't recognize the res menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>

<item
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:title="Logout"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    />

 </menu>
```

Created a new project by default and there it seems it worked. Any idea what might be?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

// Firebase
lateinit var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser
lateinit var myRef: DatabaseReference

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.uid)

    myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val users: Users? = snapshot.getValue(Users::class.java)
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "User Login : "+ users?.username, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

        }

    })
}

//Adding logout functionality
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
    return true
}

}
```

Project res structure

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your project structure, to be specific the structure of your `res` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and using import android.R doesn't work because it doesn't recognize the res menu

It will not as `android.R` does not contain the `menu` subfolder but `<insert_your_package_name_here>.R` does. You need to import the `R` with your package name and the menu will be resolved in your project after a project clean & rebuild.

Comment: wow... you pointed me right, it worked, after I checked my other projects using R resources and yes, it needed to be imported as you mentioned. it's the little things that get me

Comment: Happens to all of us at some point.